# Create a cloudant DB with Node-RED

Tags: node-red, cloudant

I want to create a new Cloudant DataBase with Node-RED to store data send by different boards. Each board has different ID and I want to create a new DB for each new ID.

Currently, I can add data on Cloudant but a DB must be specified. Does any one know how to create a new DB wether ID is not known ?

Comment: Please share some code of what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this with the current Cloudant nodes.

The connection to the database is held open from when Node-RED starts to when it shuts down, it is not opened and closed for each update/query.

The easiest way to solve the problem is just to include the board id in each update so that you can just adjust the filter to return information for a specific board.

You can then pass in the board id into the query to get the right data back.

Comment: Ok it's what I use currently, thanks for your answer